# IntelliJ Idea error: Unable to import maven project: See logs for details

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

need help about maven problem in the IntelliJ Idea.

1. I open the exiting maven projects, but i find IDEA can not recognize these projects are Maven projects.
2. I click "reimport all maven projects", and find the error:
   "17:27:17 Unable to import maven project: See logs for details"
3. Then I read the log and find error:

---

```
2015-10-21 17:27:16,608 [ 725522]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4  Build #IU-141.1532.4 
2015-10-21 17:27:16,609 [ 725523]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - JDK: 1.7.0_45 
2015-10-21 17:27:16,609 [ 725523]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
2015-10-21 17:27:16,609 [ 725523]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
2015-10-21 17:27:16,609 [ 725523]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - OS: Windows 7 
2015-10-21 17:27:16,609 [ 725523]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Last Action: Maven.Reimport 
2015-10-21 17:27:16,621 [ 725535]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Plz help me, tks.

Comment: I don't see how this question is an _exact_ duplicate of the mentioned alternative. I just had the same issue. The referenced answer tells me what an `OutOfMemory` error is and how to pass a JVM parameter - I already knew that, that's not enough to solve this problem. I'd instead love to find an answer telling me how to configure IntelliJ properly. In case somebody else got stuck, see e.g. this link showing how to configure your IDE correctly: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties. Hope that helps.